# willTransition is getting called twice

Tags: ember.js

**Goal:** prevent transitioning to another route if the current route's model has been changed (i.e. user has updated some fields but not saved, i.e. `isDirty === true`.

**Setup:** I'm using pretty much this exact code from [EmberJS.com's Routing guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/).

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition(transition) {
      if (this.controller.get('userHasEnteredData') &&
          !confirm("Are you sure you want to abandon progress?")) {
        transition.abort();
      } else {
        // Bubble the `willTransition` action so that
        // parent routes can decide whether or not to abort.
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In my controller, `userHasEnteredData` is just a computed property that watches the model's `isDirty` property.

**Issue:** When I choose to cancel from the `confirm` box (i.e. "Cancel transitioning so I can finish editing"), then the confirm box pops up again. Canceling again makes it go away for good, but I don't know why it's getting hit twice. If I instead say "ok" in the confirm the first time, it goes ahead and transitions, without popping up the confirm again. It's only when canceling the first time that it pops up immediately again.

I tried to replicate on ember-twiddle.com, but it worked fine there, calling `willTransition` only once. If it's indeed being called twice in my code, I can't figure out why, since I've checked and double-checked, and there's nothing I can see that's different that would cause the hook to be called again after `transition.abort()` runs.

Any clues?

**EDIT** I simplified `willTransition` even more, to just this, and it still runs twice. It appears that `transition.abort()` calls `willTransition()` although that makes no sense!

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      console.log('trying to transition');
      transition.abort();
    }
  }
}
//logs 'trying to transition' to the console twice!
```

Comment: How do you define the cancel action in the template?

Comment: @SteveH. The template doesn't have a cancel action as it isn't needed for these optional fields. If the user goes to this page and doesn't want to enter anything, they can go to a different page.

Comment: In your twiddle its not reproducing https://ember-twiddle.com/05eab0159ff0273977d3f872b2bbfdec?openFiles=templates.posts.show.hbs%2C&route=%2Fposts%2F2

Comment: Three years later, with Ember 2.11, I'm having the same issue. Any idea?

Comment: @paozac: Nope, still an issue for me. I have found that it's happening only when trying to transition to another nested route, but not a completely different route higher up. For example, the confirm pops twice if trying to transition from `post.edit` to `post.comments` but only once when trying to go from `post.edit` to, say `profile`.

Comment: I see, that's interesting and looks like an Ember bug to me. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @redOctober13 did you find my solution helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution works for me fine. `willTransition` is not called twice

```
willTransition(transition) {
  if (this.controller.get('model.hasDirtyAttributes') && !confirm("Are you sure you want to abandon progress?")) {
    transition.abort();
  } else {
    this.controller.get('model').rollbackAttributes();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who might be having a similar issue:

I ran into the problem of `willTransition` being fired twice when calling `transition.abort()` (in an attempt to handle unsaved changes).

In my case, the issue turned out to be related to the fact that I was returning `true` from `willTransition` in either case (whether I was handing unsaved changes, or not). I mistakenly thought that `transition.abort()` would be enough.

Once I moved the `return true;` into the else condition for my `hasChanges` `if` statement, the problem was solved.

```
willTransition(transition) {
    if (this.controller.get(model.hasDirtyAttributes)) {
        // Handle unsaved changes...
        // ...then `transition.retry()`
    } else {
        return true; // <-- this worked
    }

    // return true; <-- this fired `willTransition` twice
}
```